# Issues with installing "RcppCNPy" in R

Tags: r

I am using R 4.0.3 on a HPC CPU cluster and I am trying to install "RcppCNPy",

However, I have this error:

```
> install.packages("RcppCNPy")
Warning in install.packages("RcppCNPy") :
  'lib = "/share/apps/r/4.0.3/intel/lib64/R/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("RcppCNPy") : unable to install packages
Execution halted
```

What does "not writable" mean?
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a permissions issue, do you have the permission to write in that directory, not just R packages but in general? Maybe the problem is in `/share`. What is your OS?

Comment: How do I check for permission? I am using a high performance computing (HPC) cluster, so I guess it is clustered os

Comment: You should ask your system's sysadmin for the permissions you have, I believe they have the best answer you'll get.